# pathogen#infect() error for Nerdtree plugin installation via pathogen

Tags: vim-plugin, nerdtree

I am trying to install NerdTree plugin for vim on centos 5 using pathogen, i am getting below error on using vim command:

Error detected while processing /home/RND/narora/.vimrc:
line   14:
E117: Unknown function: pathogen#infect
Press ENTER or type command to continue

~/.vimrc file contains below pathogen code:
  execute pathogen#infect()
  syntax on
  filetype plugin indent on

~/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/      - this is the location where the plugin is installed.

can someone please help me understand what is missing over here in .vimrc, where should I place pathogen#infect() in .vimrc ?
and Is there any other files that i need to take care of?

Thanks,
Nidhi Arora

Answer (score 0):

I run the same setup, and you need to put "pathogen.vim" in ~/.vim/autoload. I do not think where you put pathogen infect is that important, but my "execute pathogen#infect()" is before any custom shortcuts I declare in my .vimrc. You can find my setup here: https://github.com/Dfenestrator/vimide This runs on CentOS 5.

Comment: Thanks Sagnik..
I placed Pathogen.vim from https://github.com/Dfenestrator/vimide in my setup :
got Error:
Change pathogen#runtime_append_all_bundles() to pathogen#incubate()
Error detected while processing /home/RND/narora/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/lib/nerdtree/tree_dir_node.vim:
line  336:
E475: Invalid argument: 117
Press ENTER or type command to continue

I replaced pathogen#runtime_append_all_bundles() to pathogen#incubate() in my .vimrc
Now again stuck with remaining part of Error in tree_dir_node.vim

Please suggest how can I proceed now??

Comment: In  github.com/Dfenestrator/vimide setup, I didn't see the .vim/bundle/nerdtree/lib/nerdtree/tree_dir_node.vim file at all...
Why is it so??
Its present in mine when I installed nerdtree from https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree.git

What I should replace in my setup to fix this?

Comment: Yeah unfortunately there was a problem in my VimIDE where not all of the plugins were being added correctly to git. I updated it, go ahead and try again.